# Postgres - create a column (alter table) as a calculation of other two columns

Tags: postgresql, autogeneratecolumn

I have a table in Posgres that contains task start and task end dates. It's possible to generate a column in this tale  as rate between (current day -start day) /(start day-end day) the column is the % of time elapse. I try in this way but does not work.

```
ALTER TABLE public.gantt_task
ADD COLUMN 
      percentage_progress 
GENERATED  ALWAYS AS (
(DATEDIFF("day", 
CURRENT_DATE,public.gantt_Tasks.start_date)) / DATEDIFF("day", public.gantt_Tasks.end_date ,public.gantt_Tasks.start_date)) 
STORED
```

Comment: Unless you created your own version, there is no `DATEDIFF` in Postgres. Try something like:`select current_date - '10/31/2020'::date; 78`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual says postgres only supports materialized (ie, stored) generated columns, which means the value is generated when the row is inserted or updated, which means it will use the insert/update date, not the CURRENT_DATE you want.

So, you need to create a view instead. This allows evaluating CURRENT_DATE at the date of the SELECT, not the INSERT/UPDATE, to generate columns.

```
CREATE VIEW foo AS SELECT *, 
  (CURRENT_DATE - public.gantt_Tasks.start_date)
  / (public.gantt_Tasks.end_date-public.gantt_Tasks.start_date)
  AS percentage_progress
FROM public.gantt_task
```

Note DATEDIFF is mysql syntax not postgres, and division by zero is not allowed, so if start_date and end_date can be identical then you'll have to modify the expression conditions depending on what you want. Also your expression will go over 100% when CURRENT_DATE is later than end_date. Perhaps something like:

```
least( 1.0, (CURRENT_DATE-start_date)/greatest( 1, end_date-start_date)::FLOAT )
```

Comment: Another alternative would be to create an immutable function that contains that expression to "trick" Postgres in allowing it for a generated column. But the view won't work either. There is no `datediff()` function in Postgres

Comment: If the function contains CURRENT_DATE then postgres won't allow it to be declared as immutable. And yeah DATEDIFF is MySQL syntax...

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a37d2e2a48cc26bf62afd9a859df7aa7

Comment: You're right, I had it mixed up with STABLE.  Doesn't change the fact the column will be generated and stored with the insert date not the select date...

Answer (score -1):

I won't write proper SQL code. But you might/should split it into two or three tasks:

1. Add new column that allows null (that should be default)
2. Update table
3. Add constrains (if required)